# How should user permissions be set when deploying rails app with capistrano and passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, centos, capistrano, passenger

I am creating and deploying a rails app using capistrano and passenger (apache). I am wondering how should the user permissions be set? Right I now my centos server has a root and thats what I am using. I believe i should create a separate account just for deployment use? If what kind of permission should the user have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be pretty generic, but the best practice is to create a new user, who has the smallest set of permissions to get the job done.